# List of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python

I have a dictionary in my python program which I initalize as follows

```
#It is initialized as empty dictionary
self.ports = {}


# ports is initialized as follows.
self.ports = {'desc':desc,'port_id':port_id,'state':state,'port_state':port_state,'number':number,'type':'port'}
```

Now there are more than one port key-value pairs that I want to store.I need a list of dictionaries.How do I initialize such a structure in Python?

Comment: The initial `self.ports = {}` is redundant if you later rebind it to another dictionary. I must confess being puzzled by what you are really struggling with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By just creating the list object as a literal, with the contained dictionary of course:

```
self.ports = [
    {'desc': desc, 'port_id': port_id, 'state': state, 'port_state': port_state,'number': number, 'type': 'port'}
]
```

A list can contain any other Python object, including dictionaries.

Python has no type declarations; your initial `self.port = {}` has no other meaning than binding the `port` attribute to an empty dictionary until such time you decide to bind it to something else.

As such, there no need, nor syntax, to tell Python that you intend to use `self.port` as a list of dictionaries. You just *do so*.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want multiple values for the same dictionary keys:

```
self.ports = {
    'desc':[desc],
    'port_id':[port_id],
    'state':[state],
    'port_state':[port_state],
    'number':[number],
    'type':['port']
}
```

You can add additions values like so

```
self.ports['desc'].append('another_description')
```